# What's the best way to handle user posting a (second) restated question?

Tags: discussion, questions, duplicate-questions

After trying to help a user in chat, I suggested that they clarify their question by posting a GIF illustrating the problem (which cleared up a misunderstanding on my part about the original issue).  I *assumed* they would edit [their existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32287894/make-uisearchbar-dismiss-like-music-app), but they asked a [second question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32289489/stop-uisearchbar-placeholder-text-from-sliding-over-on-dismissal).

So, right now, there are two "identical" questions without answers.  Do we wait for one to be answered, then flag the remaining one as a duplicate?

Should I edit the first question for now, and add a bold link to the second question, which has a clearer statement of the problem?

**Update:**  I've gone ahead and edited the original question to include the GIF and a better statement of the problem.  There are still two questions.  But I suppose I'm partial to the user getting a fresh start with the second question, and would rather see the orginal one get closed, since we didn't solve anything in all that time.

Comment: Force OP to improve their original question.

Comment: *help a user in chat*, could have instructed them beforehand to *edit* their question. :-(

Comment: Well, I said "What I would do is post that GIF in your question, and explain that you don't want the placeholder text to move back to the center".  I should have stated *edit* instead of implying it :)

Comment: system allows to close unanswered questions as duplicates, when these are asked by the same user. This is purposely made to handle cases like you describe

Comment: As @gnat said. As a side-note, on meta-sites we don't insist on any answers at all, because here many questions without answers are still useful dupe-targets.

Comment: I usually comment that they shouldn't ask a dupe and instead update their original. If they don't delete one in a reasonable amount of time then I flag for mod as exact dupe linking one in the post I'm flagging.

Comment: @codeMagic - When I was "young" in flagging, I flagged for mod just like you but I received a _"**Declined**: Please use standard close votes or close flags for this instead of flagging for moderators"_ after that I always used standard flags to don't bother moderators.

Comment: You can use the `[edit]` link in your comment to point them in the right direction. It works like this: [edit]

Comment: I just ran into the same issue with [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32311546/putting-header-on-first-image-of-post?noredirect=1#comment52518964_32311546) being a duplicate of [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32246621/isolating-and-customizing-first-image-in-wordpress-post). User said itself that it's a duplicate of his own question because "the answers provided did not work, and no new suggestions were offered". Though he accepted an answer on both question. How should I handle this, which question should I flag? (should I make a new question for this on meta?)

Comment: @vard in terms of time I'd say flag the second question, but since that one has an accepted answer I would flag the first in that case.

Comment: Close the worst one as a duplicate of the better one.

Comment: @Adriaan The problem is that I already flagged the second question yesterday, before it had an accepted answer. The flag is still pending, but it should get declined as the question to keep is the second one and not the first one. Not sure if I should custom flagged the first question in order to say to reject the first flag I raised.

Comment: @vard Just add a comment to the question explaining just this. Those voting on the review queue will hopefully see it then and close the other.

Comment: @Adriaan OP just respond to me - I asked which answer resolved the issue for him. He said "Both answers are right, but the one from this works more specifically to my needs". I don't really now what should be done in this case, just move on and let this two questions live, or ask to merge the two questions in order to keep the answers from the first one, if it is possible...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In such situations, warning the user for fixing the issue is the best way to go. Duplicate questions make it harder to reach the correct answer. There are two questions and different people are arguing the same topic on different parts of the same universe. So, first of all, situation makes it harder to get the answer for the user (that is how you could explain the situation to the user). Also, any question in here is a future reference for any programmer who runs into a such problem. Keeping them in the same place is the best.

And users (new or old) should learn the rules of the community because it is the rules that makes SO reach 10M quality questions and answers.

For dealing such problems, I prefer to warn new users. If it is an old user with some reputation, then I just down vote and vote to close, leaving a note informing that the user should merge the questions. If one of the questions is in better form than the other or have more user interactions (comments, answers etc.) then down vote and close thee the not-so-good-looking one. I prefer to support better looking question by those terms but the final word should be belong to the user.

And my advice is, do not make the dirty work of others, so they would learn how to ask and answer without the expectation that somebody will clean their mess behind them.